# Pandas - how to aggregate values between 2 ranges in a specific column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, sum, group

I'm working on a df with 2 columns e.g.

```
column1 = [False, False, False, True, False, False, True]
column2 = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

I want to sum all "False" values until the first "True" value, and again sum the following "False" values until the next "True" etc.

The output should be

```
column3 = [0,0,0,3,0,0,2]
```

I tried to sum column values but I can't "reset" the counter once hitting a "True" from a different column

Comment: @timegb not sure this is a correct duplicate, the logic seems more complex

Comment: @mozway OP will get most of the heavy lifting done with the dupe. Since OP didn't provide any attempt I'd expect them to open a new question with an attempt if there are remaining issues.

Comment: @ידיה שוואלם - Do you sum `False`s values? Or values in `column2` ? Or always `column2 == 1` ?

Comment: In another words is important `column2` for output?

Comment: @jezrael I sum column2 values, I apologize it was unclear. 
In the example above, if column2 = column2 = [3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
column3 = [0,0,0,6,0,0,2]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use:

```
df['column3'] = (df['column2']
 .mask(df['column1']) # get False values only
 .groupby(df.loc[::-1, 'column1'].cumsum()) # group with next True
 # get sum of False values only where True
 .transform('sum').where(df['column1'], 0).convert_dtypes()
)
```

Output:

```
   column1  column2  column3
0    False        1        0
1    False        1        0
2    False        1        0
3     True        1        3
4    False        1        0
5    False        1        0
6     True        1        2
```